# How do I change a given char array of numeric characters in a certain base to an int in that base?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, integer

I have a static method that takes in a char[] and an int as its parameters. The char[] array is an array of numeric characters and the int is the radix or base of the number given. I'm trying to convert the char array to an integer type in the given base, but I'm lost on how to do so. So far I created a method that takes in a char[] of a base ten number and converts it to a base 10 int.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public static int parseInt(char[] valueAsChars, int radix)
{

    char[] letters = {'A','B','C','D','E','F'};

    String convertedString = "";
    int convertedNumber = 0;
    int digit = 0;
    int counter = 1;
    char letter = '0';

    // converts array to String
    for(int arrayPlace = 0; arrayPlace < valueAsChars.length; arrayPlace++)
    {
        convertedString = convertedString + valueAsChars[arrayPlace];
    }

    //converts String to int
    for(int stringPlace = convertedString.length() - 1; stringPlace >= 0; stringPlace--)
    {
        digit = (convertedString.charAt(stringPlace)-'0');
        convertedNumber += digit * counter;
        counter *= radix;
    }
    return convertedNumber;
}
```

How do I do this but with numbers with different bases?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on exactly where you are lost?

Comment: I am confused on how I would change the char array given in the specific base (radix) to an int of the same base. For example, if a letter is given for a hexadecimal number, say {'1','2','3','A'} how would I represent that in an int value?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the existing Java methods:

```
public static int parseInt(char[] valueAsChars, int radix) {    
    return Integer.parseInt(new String(valueAsChars), radix);
}
```